# Populate records based on the visibility from Hierarchy

Tags: apex, visualforce

When user clicks VF button it's just showing all records, i want to only show the records that are visible to the user from role hierarchy, is it possible?

VF page:

```
    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:selectList id="chooseColor" value="{!picklistVal}" size="1">
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="serialnumber" itemLabel="Serial Number"/>
                <apex:selectOption itemValue="productname" itemLabel="Product Name"/>
            </apex:selectList> 
            <apex:inputText label="Search Text Here: " value="{!searchString}">
                <!-- <apex:actionSupport event="onkeypress" action="{!search}" rerender="mainBlock" status="status"/> -->
            </apex:inputText>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!search}"  />
            <apex:commandButton value="Return" action="{!returnToLoan}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>


    <apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
            <apex:commandButton value="Assign" action="{!relateToLoan}" />
            <apex:actionStatus id="status">
                <apex:facet name="start" >
                    <img src="/img/loading.gif" />                    
                </apex:facet>
            </apex:actionStatus>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>


        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!DIObjWrapper}" var="di" id="mainBlock">
            <apex:column headerValue="Add to Parent?"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!di.chk}" /></apex:column>
            <apex:column headerValue="Demo Inventory Name"><apex:outputLink value="/{!di.di.Id}">{!di.di.name}</apex:outputLink></apex:column>
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.Serial_Number__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.Product_Code__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.Product_Name__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.OwnerId}" />
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.Loan__c}" />
            <apex:column value="{!di.di.Status__c}" />
        </apex:pageBlockTable>


    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class MassInventoryAssignmentCtrl {
public String picklistVal {get; set;}
public String searchString {get; set;}
public List<diWrapper> DIObjWrapper {get; set;}
public Id loadRecordId;

public MassInventoryAssignmentCtrl(ApexPages.StandardSetController ctrl){
    this.loadRecordId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
}
public PageReference search(){
    //get users for role hierarchy
    Set<Id> childUserRoles = new Set<Id>(getAllSubRoleIds(new Set<Id>{UserInfo.getUserRoleId()}));
    System.debug(childUserRoles);

    String searchQuery = 'Select id, name, Serial_Number__c, Status__c, Product_Code__c, OwnerId, Product_Name__c, Loan__c from Demo_Inventory__c where (Status__c like \'%With Sales Rep%\')';

    if(picklistVal == 'serialnumber' && searchString <> null && searchString <> ''){
        searchQuery  += ' and Serial_Number__c like \'%'+ searchString.trim() +'%\' ';
    }

    if(picklistVal == 'productname' && searchString <> null && searchString <> ''){
        searchQuery += ' and Product_Name__c like \'%'+ searchString.trim() +'%\' ';
    }

    searchQuery += ' limit 500';
    System.debug('searchQuery > ' + searchQuery);
    List<Demo_Inventory__c> DIObj = Database.query(searchQuery);
    //System.debug('Database.query(searchQuery) > ' + this.DIObj);
    if(DIObj <> null && DIObj.size() > 0){
        DIObjWrapper = new List<diWrapper>();
        for(Demo_Inventory__c di : DIObj){
            if(di <> null)
                DIObjWrapper.add(new diWrapper(false, di));
        }
    }

    return null;
}
public static Set<ID> getAllSubRoleIds(Set<ID> roleIds) {

    Set<ID> currentRoleIds = new Set<ID>();

    // get all of the roles underneath the passed roles
    for(UserRole userRole :[select Id from UserRole where ParentRoleId 
                            IN :roleIds AND ParentRoleID != null]) {
                                currentRoleIds.add(userRole.Id);
                            }

    // go fetch some more rolls!
    if(currentRoleIds.size() > 0) {
        currentRoleIds.addAll(getAllSubRoleIds(currentRoleIds));
    }

    return currentRoleIds;
}

public PageReference relateToLoan(){
    System.debug('DIObjWrapper > ' + DIObjWrapper);
    if(DIObjWrapper <> null && DIObjWrapper.size() > 0 && loadRecordId <> null){
        List<Demo_Inventory__c> diListToUpdate = new List<Demo_Inventory__c>();
        for(diWrapper diObj : DIObjWrapper){
            if(diObj.chk && diObj.di.Loan__c == null)
                diListToUpdate.add(new Demo_Inventory__c(id = diObj.di.id, Loan__c = this.loadRecordId));
        }
        System.debug('diListToUpdate > ' + diListToUpdate);
        if(diListToUpdate <> null && diListToUpdate.size() > 0)
            update diListToUpdate;

        PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+this.loadRecordId);
        pageRef.setRedirect(true);
        System.debug(pageRef);
        return pageRef;
    }
    return null;
}
public PageReference returnToLoan(){
    System.debug('Return to loan');
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('/'+this.loadRecordId);
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    System.debug(pageRef);
    return pageRef;
}
public class diWrapper{
    public Boolean chk {get; set;}
    public Demo_Inventory__c di {get; set;}
    public diWrapper(Boolean chk, Demo_Inventory__c di){
        this.chk = chk;
        this.di = di;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the Organization-Wide Default for `Demo_Inventory__c`? If it is set to Private, you need to declare your controller `with sharing`.

Comment: It's set to private, how to declare the class with sharing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce will implement the visibility restriction for you. You need to declare a sharing model on your class.

```
public class MassInventoryAssignmentCtrl {
```

needs to be

```
public with sharing class MassInventoryAssignmentCtrl {
```

`with sharing` classes enforce Salesforce's record-level visibility rules. `without sharing` classes, and those with no declaration, bypass these rules, which can lead in situations like Visualforce pages to users accessing data to which they have no right.

I'd encourage reading through [Using the with sharing, without sharing, and inherited sharing Keywords](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm). This is a really important area, and it's best to always explicitly declare a sharing model on your classes so that you can predict how they will behave.

Comment: wow that was easy so if we create sharing rules would that apply as well?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.